# Most efficient way to check if numbers in a list is divisible by another number

Tags: python

So I just finished a coding test yesterday and I'm a tad neurotic. I was asked to create a class or function to check if elements in a list were all divisible by a scalable list of elements. This is the best I could come up with and was wondering if this could be improved. Thanks! And to get in front of it, I deliberately used a partial instead of lambda. To me it is much cleaner, and allows for better code re-use. Plus, I think Guido strongly discourages the use of Lambda and advises people switch to partials.

```
from functools import partial

def is_divisible(mod_vals, num):
    """A partial that runs a number against the list of modulus arguments, returning a bool value"""
    for mod in mod_vals:
        if num%mod != 0:
            return False
    return True

def divisible_by_factor(*mod_vals):
    """Returns a list based off a scalable amount of modulus arguments, no range support currently"""
    comparison_list = []
    div_partial = partial(is_divisible, (mod_vals))
    for i in range(1, 100):
        if div_partial(num=i):
            comparison_list.append(i)
    return comparison_list
```

Comment: You could use `any` in `is_divisible`. Also, the docstring implies that it is only ever used as a partial, which is confusing. Also, might be a better question for CodeReview.

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k I've never actually used any before. How would that work in the context of this? It looked like it only took an iterable in the docs.And totally agree about the docstring just wanted a way to denote the purpose of each function as it applied to the test.

Comment: Minor observation: I encourage the use of positive logic when possible.  `if num%mod == 0: return True` is easier to grok than `if num%mod != 0: return False`

Comment: @JS I normally shoot for that but didn't want to iterate the list if a failing condition was already met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> def divisible_by_factor(mod_vals):
>>>     return [i for i in range(1, 100) if all(i % j == 0 for j in mod_vals)]
>>> print divisible_by_factor([2, 3, 5])
[30, 60, 90]
```

For every `i` test whether it's divisible by all provided values. Keep only values that pass this test.